# OpenLayers projected to different location Vs Bing Maps

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers with bing map. I have added a marker but it is displaying on different location. Same coordinates I have used in bing maps and it shows on correct location.

Here [bing search result](http://www.bing.com/maps/#Y3A9MzEuNTYzMzAwfjc0LjMxMzMwMCZsdmw9NCZzdHk9dSZxPS0yMi4zODY5NjA4JTJDJTIwLTQ5Ljc2MDI3MDg=)

[image]

This is the OpneLayers result

[image]

```
    $(function () {

        var tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
                key: 'Armnl..',
                imagerySet: 'Aerial'
            })
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [tileLayer],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [-22.3869608, -49.7602708],
                zoom: 5,
            })
        });

        var p1 = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point([-22.3869608, -49.7602708])
        });


        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [p1]
        });

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        });

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

    });
```

Would I need to transform the coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, you need to tranform your coords to `EPSG:3857`.

You have 2 different options

1) you build your map using epsg:4326. That means client tile reprojection shall take place.

To do so

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [tileLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection:'EPSG:4326',
        center: [-22.3869608, -49.7602708],
        zoom: 5,
    })
});
```

2) You tranfrom your center to 'EPSG:3857'. This projection shall be used as you do not specify it within the ol.view config. (projection automatic getted from the first tile layer attached to the map).

To do so

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [tileLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-22.3869608, -49.7602708], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857');
        zoom: 5,
    })
});
```

end for your vector point

```
var p1 = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([-22.3869608, -49.7602708], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'))
        });
```

Comment: I have tried both options but still marker added to wrong position. How can transform unknown coordinates to EPSG:3857?

Comment: just flip the coordinates from this `center: ol.proj.transform([-22.3869608, -49.7602708]` to this `center: ol.proj.transform([-49.7602708,-22.3869608] `. Do the same for your vector point. Your coordinates are not unknown it is wgs84 lon/lat.